# iOS Universal Links redirect to AppStore to Update Application

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I am working on a feature that implementing of 3rd party sdk (Firebase etc) to handle Universal Links in iOS and my apple-app-site-association file is like below.

```
{
  "applinks": {
     "apps": [],
     "details": [
        {
          "appID": "teamid.bundleid",
          "paths": [
              "NOT /auth", 
              "/*"
           ]
       },
     ]
   }
}
```

Everything is working fine but in a domain like `myappsite.com/deeplink/live-chat` it goes directly to the AppStore but the problem here is my application is already installed on the phone, when I go to AppStore, there is a button named Update for updating application then nothing changed, do you have any idea of this problem?

Comment: Does your project contain URL types corresponding to your domain?

Comment: @BulatYakupov yes, it's already added applinks:mydomins.com style, but it don't work just on endpoint, it redirect on this

Comment: which endpoints work fine and which not?

Comment: there are many endpoints like for example /deeplink/user/* but the buggy endpoint is /deeplink/live-chat

Comment: try to include this path in paths

Comment: Hey @BulatYakupov sorry for late reply, when I install prod from xcode there's no problem but when you install it from appstore it gets redirection

Comment: Does your server configured correctly? After you create the apple-app-site-association file, upload it to the root of your HTTPS web server or to the .well-known subdirectory. The file needs to be accessible via HTTPS—without any redirects—at https://<domain>/apple-app-site-association or https://<domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association. Next, you need to handle universal links in your app.